# Literary translation production: How much does it help with a language?

Tags: learning-methods, teaching-methods, translation, literature

Can anyone comment, preferably with evidence, on the benefit to language learners of translating literary works from their target language into their native language --specifically with a goal of maintaining the art, nuances, etc. of the original?

Related: 
[Evidence that translating L2 into L1 improves L2 acquisition](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/3427/evidence-that-translating-l2-into-l1-improves-l2-acquisition)

Orthogonally related: [Will having a part time or freelancing translation job affect my effort of thinking in second language?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/416/will-having-a-part-time-or-freelancing-translation-job-affect-my-effort-of-think)

Answer (score 1):

I'm the live evidence of that, I'm a literary translator. I started as a teenager by translating a (fairly easy) poem by Lorca. Translating literary works can bring great benefits but the learners must be ready for it. They must have an ear for their native language (things like style differences etc), the literary work should be something they can relate to and be interested in reading.